# Cannot save TIF file using GDI+

Tags: vb.net, gdi, tiff

I have a vb.net app that selects and loads a JPG file

```
 LoadedImage = Image.FromFile(InputImageName)
```

then attempts to save the file as a TIF using GDI+

```
 LoadedImage.Save(TIF_ImageName, ImageFormat.Tiff)
```

There are no syntax errors, but the save fails with

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
Message=Conversion from string "System.Runtime.InteropServices.E" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

I have tried using a bitmap instead of image, no joy
The image is large (9000x11000 pixels)
Is this an `encoderparams` issue - perhaps there is no default?, and the available samples for that were for a bitonal image.

In the end, I will be generating new TIF Tags with location data, so this is an interim step in the development.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [ImageCodecInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo) class, which provides means to control the codec parameters used to encode an Image format.

In GDI+, you can specify a really limited number of parameters. In practice, just the [Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression) method and the [Quality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.quality) level, which determines the compression level (`0-100`, where `0` is the maximum compression).

These parameters are *assembled* in a [EncoderParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameters) array of [EncoderParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter.-ctor) objects - used to specify the [Encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder) cathegory - before passing them to the [Image.Save()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save) overload that accepts the an **`ImageCodecInfo`** and **`EncoderParameters`** as arguments.

**Sample method call**:
Save a source image to a TIFF format, using the same DPI setting, compression level set to `50%`. The image is saved as in `24bpp RGB` Format. Modify as required.
The compression type is `LZW`.

```
Dim jpgImage As Image = Image.FromFile("ImageFile.jpg"), True)
SaveTiffImage(jpgImage, jpgImage.VerticalResolution, 50L, "DestinationFile.tif")
jpgImage.Dispose()
```

**Codec initialization method**:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports ImageCodec = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder

Private Sub SaveTiffImage(image As Image, resolution As Single, compressionLevel As Long, fileName As String)
    resolution = Math.Max(72, Math.Min(2400, resolution))
    compressionLevel = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(100, compressionLevel))

    Using bitmap = New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
        bitmap.SetResolution(resolution, resolution)
        Using g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
            g.DrawImage(image, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size),
                               New Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            Dim codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().
                        FirstOrDefault(Function(enc) enc.FormatID = ImageFormat.Tiff.Guid)
            Dim qualityParam =
                New EncoderParameter(ImageCodec.Quality, compressionLevel)
            Dim compressionParam =
                New EncoderParameter(ImageCodec.Compression, EncoderValue.CompressionLZW)
            Using codecParms = New EncoderParameters(2)
                codecParms.Param(0) = qualityParam
                codecParms.Param(1) = compressionParam
                bitmap.Save(fileName, codec, codecParms)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

**C# version**:

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using ImageCodec = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder;

private void SaveTiffImage(Image image, float resolution, long compressionLevel, string fileName)
{
    resolution = Math.Max(72, Math.Min(2400, resolution));
    compressionLevel = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(100, compressionLevel));

    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
    {
        bitmap.SetResolution(resolution, resolution);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size), 
                               new Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            var imageCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
                                .FirstOrDefault(enc => enc.FormatID == ImageFormat.Tiff.Guid);
            if (imageCodec == null)
                throw new NotSupportedException("TIFF Conversion not suppoted", 
                      new NullReferenceException("TIFF Codec reference missing"));
            var qualityParam = 
                new EncoderParameter(ImageCodec.Quality, compressionLevel);
            var compressionParam = 
                new EncoderParameter(ImageCodec.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW);
            using (var codecParms = new EncoderParameters(2))
            {
                codecParms.Param[0] = qualityParam;
                codecParms.Param[1] = compressionParam;
                bitmap.Save(fileName, imageCodec, codecParms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and Thanks! A few changes were required to remove errors -  2 lines were modified Dim qualityParam = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, compressionLevel)
                Dim compressionParam = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, EncoderValue.CompressionLZW)

Comment: Why would this: `Imports ImageCodec = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder` generate errors? It's a standard `Imports` modification to avoid conflicts with other namespaces/classes which use the same name. In this case, the `Text.Encoder` namespace. What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Hi Jimi - <I am on Vs2015 > could this be the issue?  here are the 3 changes 
 . . .<removed> Imports ImageCodec = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder - VS said not needed, but the 2 lines referencing ImageCodec were modified to using encoder.Quality and Encoder.Compression  (Dim qualityParam =
                New EncoderParameter(encoder.Quality, compressionLevel)
            Dim compressionParam =
                New EncoderParameter(encoder.Compression, EncoderValue.CompressionLZW))

Comment: Doesn't matter what Visual Studio says. That Import is needed and you can leave as it is. `ImageCodec` is `System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder`, which is better left as is, since you may also need a reference to `System.Text` (which also has an `Encoder` class) and this setting avoids the conflict that arises if you Import both namespaces. I still don't know if you were able to convert the images.

Comment: Hi and thanks - The issue was VS2015 - I switched to VS2019 (with some minor grief ) and changed the code back to your suggested and Voila - got my first TIF! Next task is to add location data as tags so that ArcMap can load the file and properly display it using WGS84